# Пагинация на кастомной странице

Tags: wordpress, pagination, пагинация

всем привет, очень прошу помощи тк уже много всего перепробовала..
делаю свою тему на ворпрессе. есть шаблон страницы Блог, выводятся кастомный тип поста Blog. нужна пагинация, но она не работает.
в Reading Settings выбирала эту страницу, настраивала количество постов. но при клике на любую след страницу выдает 404. вставляла этот код и в index.php, но ничего. работает только на главной странице. Даже подключала плагин, но ошибка все та же. Подскажите, что тут нужно поменять и в чем может быть дело?

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Template name: Blog
     */
    get_header(); ?>

<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="blog__wrap d-grid d-grid-2">
            <?php 
                global $wp_query;
                $current = absint(
                    max(
                        1,
                        get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' )
                    )
                );
                
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'page' => $current );
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="blog-item d-flex-sb-center ">
                                 <div class="title title-24"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <?php endwhile;
                           
                            the_posts_pagination();  
                            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            <?php else:  ?>
                            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; 
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
   
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: В условии `get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' )` в else должно быть `get_query_var( 'page' )`.

Comment: не помогает к сожалению(

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-нибудь пригодится.
Смогла решить. был слаг страницы /blog, изменила на /blog-page. так же помог комментарий выше про условие и в аргументах нужно заменить 'page' => $current на 'paged' => $current